# Using regex to store text before and after two different characters

Tags: regex, windows, bulk-rename-utility

I have a series of files that have this format:

> 01x05e - Some text (Some more text)
>   01x05f - Some text (Some more text)
>   01x05g - Some text (Some more text)

What I'd like to to is strip them to produce this:

> 01x05e - Some more text
>   01x05f - Some more text
>   01x05g - Some more text

To do this, I am using the Bulk Rename Utility. I thought I had some regex I could use to do this:

```
-.*?\(
```

This successfully matches everything between the "-" and the "(" above. I was hoping I could use it to remove all of that text, before asking the Bulk Rename Utility to do a very trivial removal of the final character in every filename (i.e. the ")").

However, in Bulk Rename Utility I can't just match the text and replace it with no content to remove it. Instead, I have to specify a replace criteria and nothing I'm entering seems to be working. Any time I enter any data in the "replace" section it simply erases all of my filename.

This leads me to think I need to approach the regex differently and find some way of grabbing the data before the "-" and grabbing the data between both "(" and ")" and placing them together.

However, I've no idea how to even start doing this. Is this the correct approach, or am I missing something obvious with regards to the match and replace of the regex I currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bulk Rename Utility has a support website, including a forum that features a section providing regex rename support, [here](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/forum/viewforum.php?f=3).

It seems like you want to capture from the first paren (open) to the last paren (close) and delete everything after the first hyphen. Capturing groups are your friend here:

```
^([^-]* -)   - This will match from start to first hyphen after space.

[^(]*    - This will match everything except open paren.

\((.*)\)$ - This will match things inside the parens.
```

You can put it all together:

```
^([^-]* -)[^(]*\((.*)\)$
```

And replace it with just the first group and the last group:

```
\1 \2
```

Comment: Just amazing. Thank you very much.